# Why doesn't the task scheduler wake up the laptop?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

The task executes, but it the cannot wake up computer in sleep **(not hibernation)** .

> Task's parameters:
>
> ## **General:**
>
> Run only when user logged on
> With highest privileges
> Configure to win10
> User: standart User with admin rights
>
> *Also I tried "run whether user is logged on or not", but  with this task does not start at all. Result was same when I tried change User to "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" *
>
> ## **Trigger:**
>
> On a schedule
> On time
> Enabled
>
> *(time is correct, because not in sleep mode everything works fine)*
>
> ## **Action:**
>
> Start a cmd
>
> ## **Conditions:**
>
> Wake the computer to run this task
>
> ## **Settings**
>
> Allow task to be run on demand
> If the task is already running run a new instance of the job

## **Logs**

When I use User:

> The Task Scheduler successfully completed an instance of "{ed908aff-00e3-4abb-8ced-000a25942e73}" of wakeUp" for the user "DESKTOP-VFAG0F4 User".

When I change user to System or choose "run whether user is logged on or not" option in General:

> The task is carried out in present

## **I tried:**

- All ways from https://windowsreport.com/task-scheduler-wont-turn...
  **(In addition to creating a new user, the standard one already has an admin rights)
- Way from [Windows 10 doesn't wake up by task after sleep task (via Task Scheduler)](https://superuser.com/questions/1510992/windows-10-doesnt-wake-up-by-task-after-sleep-task-via-task-scheduler)
  **